# Integer Comparison through Predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using core data in which I am having an entity called **"Scan"** who is having one attribute say **electronic_id** which is of `NSNumber` type. Now suppose in data base i am having 3 entries of this **Scan** attribute.

- One entry of this entity having 35 as `electronic_id`.
- Second entry of this entity having 354 as `electronic_id`.
- Third entry of this entity having 375 as `electronic_id`.

I am performing searching on this attribute. so I when i start to search entity by passing 3 i want all these 3 objects.when i pass 35 then i want first two objects.

I want partial matches objects on `NSNumber` through predicate.
I am using this function.

```
-(void)filteredContentWithSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    if([searchText length])
    {
        int value=0;
        value=[searchText intValue];

        if ([strSelectedType isEqualToString:@"Electronic ID"])
        {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"electronic_id == %d",value];
            NSManagedObjectContext *context =[self managedObjectContext];
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Scan" inManagedObjectContext:context];

            [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
            NSError *error=nil;
            NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
            if (error==nil)
            {

            }
            else if (error!=nil)
            {
                NSArray *results =[APP_DELEGATE CallForGetScan:YES Predicateis:predicate];
                [arrSessionSearchData removeAllObjects];
                [arrSessionSearchData addObjectsFromArray:results];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help how to compare integer in `NSPredicate`.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try cast integer to string and compare it

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"electronic_id.stringValue CONTAINS[c] %@",searchText];
```

Comment: @user1960279, I don't ask up vote, just accept, please look tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour is should help you understand rules

Answer (score 1):

@sage444 your answer is what I have looking for hours. Works like a charm.

I just provide Swift version for future readers:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.stringValue CONTAINS[c] %@",
                            #keyPath(YOUR_MODEL.number),
                            substring)
```