# CoreData, create predicate which check substring in number

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

In my database model I have entity with attribute of `Int64` type. I want to fetch objets that match to my substring number predicate.

Predicate should tests if given number is a part of being check number.

Data: [5, 25, 154, 7988, 565647, 2, 687, 165255]

In: 5
Out: [5, 25, 154, 565647, 165255]

Int: 25
Out: [25, 165255]

Int: 656
Out: [565647]

Is it possible? If not, how to handle it? Should I change my attribute type to String?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22781106/1801544 ?

Comment: Works like a charm, tnx. Do you know something about complexity of this casting? Is it the optimal solution?

Comment: That's not really a casting. That's calling `absoluteString` method on a `NSNumber` object which are classic methods.

Comment: So it should works quickly, tnx for explanation. You can create an answer with this information. I will check it as answered. Tnx one more time.

Comment: oh I understand, should I delete this question?

Comment: I'll just mark the question as duplicate. You can do as such, you don't have to delete your question. If you didn't find it by yourself, maybe someone else will only also find yours and could be then redirected on the other one.

Comment: so I leave it for the future readers

Comment: Could you mark it yourself as duplicate? I can only flag it as such (and there is 4 needed others flags) and since you are the author you should be able to close it as duplicate.

Comment: done :) tnx for explanation StackOverflow guidelines :P